# twitter integration in C#

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to integrate twitter in my ASP.Net web site with C# . I want to implement a profile page in which user should be able to sign in from twitter. After clicking on "Sign Up via Twitter" Button. I have made a twitter application and i am doing this thing with OAuth. After getting user details i want to add them to my SQL Server Database(So that in future user can sign in using these details).

Now when i build the solution it build successfully, but gives an exception at runtime. The exception comes at Line # 2. The exception is

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
so please answer if you have done this kind of problem.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your connection is, but you can use a twitter's library at:

http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2013/jun/asptwitter

A basic example at:

http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2013/jul/twitter_api_proxy

Is important to check:

consumer_key = 'YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY'

consumer_secret = 'YOUR-CONSUMER-SECRET'

access_token = 'YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN'

access_secret = 'YOUR-ACCESS-SECRET'